# Generate groups of pairings without duplicates, php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have looked for a year to try to figure this one out.  I am trying to build a bracket running system, for running bowling brackets.

I have a table with an ID column and a BowlerID column, call it bowling_bracket_entries.  The ID is unique, but there can be multiple entries of the same BowlerID, ranging from 8 to 1 entry.  What I want to do is make pairs from the BowlerID row, but never repeat the same pair, then from those pairings, put them in groups of 4 pairs where no BowlerID repeats within that group of 4 pairings.

Structure of the bowling.bracket_entries table
ID | BowlerID

```
 766    151
767 230
768 201
769 202
770 140
771 205
772 62
773 75
774 56
775 140
759 129
760 60
761 165
762 223
763 145
764 131
765 145
704 197
705 230
706 202
707 167
708 223
709 205
710 217
711 217
712 56
713 60
714 141
715 60
716 193
717 181
718 217
719 75
720 218
721 151
722 223
723 202
724 197
725 140
726 220
727 203
728 56
729 62
730 218
731 160
732 205
733 141
734 167
735 165
736 151
737 205
738 224
739 203
740 142
741 181
742 60
743 60
744 218
745 217
746 224
747 160
748 218
749 223
750 203
751 193
752 202
753 62
754 60
755 142
756 201
757 151
758 203
```

I tried randomly selecting 2 BowlerID's and putting them together with a delimiter (ie 22~100), then inserting into a Pairings table, then pull the next pairing (ie 36~92), create a variable reverse of that pair (ie 92~36), and check the Pairing table for values that match either, if not found, it inserts, removes the ID of those BowlerIDs from the Entries table and repeats until it runs out of values. Problem is sometimes I get a BowlerID paired with itself.  Occasionally, I will get a complete list with no BowlerID's paired with themselves.

```
SELECT bracket_entries.ID, bracket_entries.BowlerID FROM bracket_entries ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 2
```

Then put them together and create a pairing (ie 36~68)

```
$i = 0;
    while($pairing=$rsNewPair->fetch_assoc()) {
        //Build Pairing List
        $thisPairing .= $pairing['BowlerID'];
        $IDS .= $pairing['ID'];
        $i++;
            if($i < 2){
                $thisPairing .= "~";
                $IDS .= "~";
            }
        }


$flipFlop = explode('~', $thisPairing);
    $reversePairing = $flipFlop[1].'~'.$flipFlop[0];
    if($flipFlop[0] == $flipFlop[1]){
        header("Refresh:0");
    }
```

And compare to what is already in there.

```
SELECT bracket_pairings.Pairing FROM bracket_pairings WHERE bracket_pairings.Pairing = '".$thisPairing."' OR bracket_pairings.Pairing = '".$reversePairing."'"
```

If it doesn't find anything, then insert the pairing into the Pairings table and move on to the next 2

bowling_bracket_pairings table structure

```
    1 203~218
2 193~218
3 217~129
4 201~60
5 60~141
6 141~165
7 197~202
8 230~203
9 220~167
10 60~62
11 151~140
12 151~230
13 193~205
14 60~140
15 217~223
16 203~142
17 60~205
18 197~151
19 205~201
20 218~62
21 56~223
22 217~167
23 56~202
24 217~75
25 224~223
26 160~203
27 151~60
28 131~145
29 140~205
30 202~75
31 62~160
32 142~181
33 224~181
34 145~223
35 165~56
36 218~202

SELECT
PairingID, SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pairing, '~', 1) AS entry1,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(Pairing, '~', 2), '~', -1) AS entry2
```

FROM bracket_pairings

Then use a while loop to display the pairings in brackets and push each entry into an array for the 4 pairs until it is full and then compare to make sure any user is not duplicated.

```
while(($pairings=$rsEntries->fetch_assoc())&&($loop < 5)){
    $thisBowlerID1 = $pairings['entry1'];
    $thisBowlerID2 = $pairings['entry2'];

    if((!in_array($thisBowlerID1, $thisBracket)) || (!in_array($thisBowlerID2, $thisBracket))){
    while($players=$rsPlayers->fetch_assoc()){
            if($players['BowlerID'] == $thisBowlerID1){
                echo $players['BowlerID'].'<br>';
                //echo $players['Name'].'('.$players['CurrentAvg'].')<br>';
            } 
    } mysqli_data_seek($rsPlayers, 0);
    array_push($thisBracket, $thisBowlerID1);

    while($players=$rsPlayers->fetch_assoc()){
        if($players['BowlerID'] == $thisBowlerID2){
            echo $players['BowlerID'].'<br><br>';
            //echo $players['Name'].'('.$players['CurrentAvg'].')<br><br>';
    } 
    } mysqli_data_seek($rsPlayers, 0);
    array_push($thisBracket, $thisBowlerID2);

    $removeSQL="DELETE FROM bracket_pairings WHERE bracket_pairings.PairingID = ".$pairings['PairingID'];
    $removePairing = $connAdmin->query($removeSQL);
    $loop++;
    }
    $thisBracket = array();
}
}
```

I have 72 entries When I try to put them in groups of 4 (8 entries), It never seems to fill up the 9 brackets, just about 7.5 and then leave a random assortment of pairings left in the table that didn't get placed, yet I still have openings.

Result

```
    Bracket 1
62
141

142
151

131
218

140
56

Bracket 2
145
201

193
160

56
205

129
203

Bracket 3
167
75

217
201

224
217

230
140

Bracket 4
60
193

203
197

141
167

223
220

Bracket 5
60
165

202
142

181
60

202
202

Bracket 6
205
140

62
218

217
60

230
223

Bracket 7
165
223

205
218

205
75

56
151

Bracket 8
202
203
```

As you can see the result leave 8 unfilled.

Here is what is left over that didn't get included:

```
5   197~218
10  60~223
15  181~62
20  203~60
25  160~217
30  151~151
35  145~224
```

Not sure why every fifth one has skipped.  I think I am on the right track, but any help or ideas to figure out how to fix the issues that I am having would be great.

Comment: Please edit your question so it does contain the full table specification for your tables `Entries` and `Pairing`. Specially because you talk about a column `UserID` but your queries use `BracketId` instead. Also the table names doesn't seem the same between your description and the SQL queries. Also, add a full example of your 72 entries and how you want them to be filled in your 9 brackets. And explain how the 72 initial entries get filled. Maybe also show another filling into the 9 brackets with the same 72 entries, which however are paired wrong (and mark that row).

Comment: I updated the question, hopefully it clarifies a little bit better.  Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first: Don't save the pairings as a string like "203~60". It makes it harder to work with the database when you have to combine/split the values all the time. Your tables should be in [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form).

Second: Don't save the pairings in the database when you are still building the pairings. Keep them in the memory of your php to avoid any unnecessary database calls just to see if the pairing is already added, it is much faster that way.

That being said, there are some algorithms you can lookup for your problem. You should check the following links:

- [Is there a known algorithm for scheduling tournament matchups?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/165594/is-there-a-known-algorithm-for-scheduling-tournament-matchups) an their related questions on softwareengineering.stackexchange.com (this might be even a better place to ask, but check for duplicates)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking

I can think of some algorithm, but it fails in some situations. The algorithm would work like this:
You use the algorithm on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm to create a scheduling for 9 teams with 8 members each. Let assume they are called "a" to "i". The pairings will look like this:

```
abcd  aibc  ahib  aghi afgh
hgfe  gfed  fedc  edcb dcbi

aefg  adef  acde  bcfg
cbih  bihg  ihgf  dehi
```

You get this seeding by holding the "a" team in place and rotate the remaining teams around the table/pairings. However you have to skip one team since you have 9 teams for 4*2 possible seeds. In the ninth group the  "a" team is missing and it contains the remaining seedings of "b" to "i".

When we have these 9 teams with 8 members each they could be represented as this:

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccc
dddddddd
eeeeeeee
ffffffff
gggggggg
hhhhhhhh
iiiiiiii
```

When you have more than 9 teams you should try to pair them together like they belong together to one pseudo-team of size 8. This can be looked like this:

```
aaaaaabb
ccccddde
fffffggg
hhiijjjj
kkkkklll
mmmmnnnn
ooopppqq
rrrrrsss
ttuuvvww
```

Since these teams would be on "the same" pseudo team, they don't match against each other and the algorithm still works.

However, the algorithm fail when you cannot put the teams in pseudo teams of size 8. Assume you have 2 teams of 8 members and 8 teams of size 7. The
pseudo teams would look like this:

```
aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb
cccccccj
dddddddj
eeeeeeej
fffffffj
gggggggj
hhhhhhhj
iiiiiiij
```

In this situation, eventually the "8th" player of the row "c" might play against the "8th" player of the row "d", but they are actually on the same team. You might try to be tricky to move the "8th" player of the row "c" to a different place in the "c" row. But when you are on this road of fixing, you can use a backtracking algorithm instead anyway.

By backtracking you brute force all the combinations and skip a combination when you found that the solution doesn't work. Check the URL above to understand backtracking (the animated gif might be helpful).